# Spurned downvote after seeking clarification on a question

Tags: support, downvotes, serial-voting

I was seeking to ask an OP's attempts to a question, but they were not happy with the comments I posted and they went on a rampage to down-vote 20 of my answers. I suspect the author of the question was responsible for it. Either way, what action should I do now?

[image]

Comment: You're at 32k rep and it's your first down seeing serial voting? Impressive :p. Nothing to do on your part. An automated script should revert these soon.

Comment: Welcome to the club. This happens to everyone at some point. These "revenge downvotes" will be reverted automatically. If the user makes a habit out of serial downvoting users, they will be suspended.

Comment: Thanks guys! Not sure why such spurned behavior occurs when I did nothing personally, but just go by the rules of the community

Comment: If only we knew. Some users like to just go and give themselves justice this way. Not realizing it does nothing....

Comment: It might have been a good idea if you stopped 2 comments earlier on that post.

Comment: @Patrice: Yes wish they know better than doing that, by just improving their quality of posts

Comment: @AndréKool: Not sure what you are referring to, took it from the `?tab=reputation` page

Comment: Keep in mind that as voting is still anonymous you can't be 100% sure who voted. Anyone who is annoyed by your comments from the last 6 to 8 weeks could have decided to start that downvote party. Calling out users publicly will back-fire, specially if you got it wrong ...

Comment: @Inian in that case you should notice that at his reputation graph

Comment: @fubo and Inian. Is it a good idea to point fingers like this?

Comment: @AndréKool: I was just trying to look into the rep tab to see, but it was that obvious as fubo says. I admit, it is wrong to accuse, but this is a straight forward case of hate votes

Comment: @AndréKool: It's not like the user is difficult to find, any way...

Comment: @Cerbrus still no need to do the public blaming and shaming. it is not a mod we're dealing here with ...

Comment: So just another clarification guys, so how many times can people do such hate votes, does the community keep track of how many a time each person(s) do this? Any action on their profiles if this behavior is repetetive?

Comment: @Inian: The exact threshold is secret, for good reason. If they repeatedly have their votes reverted, they'll get suspended, eventually.

Comment: The person responsible has been warned, and the system should invalidate these votes within a day. If they aren't, flag us in 48 hours and we'll have them manually invalidated.

Comment: @BradLarson: Thanks a lot, just a question. How do I flag for this specific issue? Just flag on any one of my downvoted answers referring this issue?

Comment: Yes, a flag on any post stating that you've been targeted will cause moderators to look into it. Patterns like the above are pretty obvious to detect and invalidate. We track these so that we can file manual invalidation requests if the daily invalidation script doesn't work.